# Future.cancel() followed by Future.get() kills my thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, executorservice

I want to use the *Executor* interface (using *Callable*) in order to start a *Thread* (let's call it callable Thread) which will do work that uses blocking methods.
That means the callable Thread can throw an *InterruptedException* when the main Thread calls the *Future.cancel(true)* (which calls a *Thread.interrupt()*).

**I also want my callable Thread to properly terminate when interrupted USING other blocking methods** in a cancellation part of code.

While implementing this, I experienced the following behavior: When I call *Future.cancel(true)* method, the callable Thread is correctly notified of the interruption **BUT if the main Thread immediately waits for its termination using *Future.get()*, the callable Thread is kind of *killed* when calling any blocking method**.

The following *JUnit 5* snippet illustrates the problem.
We can easily reproduce it if the main Thread does not sleep between the *cancel()* and the *get()* calls.
If we sleep a while but not enough, we can see the callable Thread doing half of its cancellation work.
If we sleep enough, the callable Thread properly completes its cancellation work.

**Note 1**: I checked the *interrupted* status of the callable Thread: it is correctly set once and only once, as expected.

**Note 2**: When debugging step by step my callable Thread after interruption (when passing into the cancellation code), I "loose" it after several step when entering a blocking method (no *InterruptedException* seems to be thrown).

```
    @Test
    public void testCallable() {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        System.out.println("Main thread: Submitting callable...");
        final Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(() -> {

            boolean interrupted = Thread.interrupted();

            while (!interrupted) {
                System.out.println("Callable thread: working...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Callable thread: Interrupted while sleeping, starting cancellation...");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                interrupted = Thread.interrupted();
            }

            final int steps = 5;
            for (int i=0; i<steps; ++i) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Callable thread: Cancelling (step %d/%d)...", i+1, steps));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Assertions.fail("Callable thread: Should not be interrupted!");
                }
            }

            return null;
        });

        final int mainThreadSleepBeforeCancelMs = 2000;
        System.out.println(String.format("Main thread: Callable submitted, sleeping %d ms...", mainThreadSleepBeforeCancelMs));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(mainThreadSleepBeforeCancelMs);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Assertions.fail("Main thread: interrupted while sleeping.");
        }

        System.out.println("Main thread: Cancelling callable...");
        future.cancel(true);
        System.out.println("Main thread: Cancelable just cancelled.");

        // Waiting "manually" helps to test error cases:
        // - Setting to 0 (no wait) will prevent the callable thread to correctly terminate;
        // - Setting to 500 will prevent the callable thread to correctly terminate (but some cancel process is done);
        // - Setting to 1500 will let the callable thread to correctly terminate.
        final int mainThreadSleepBeforeGetMs = 0;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(mainThreadSleepBeforeGetMs);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Assertions.fail("Main thread: interrupted while sleeping.");
        }

        System.out.println("Main thread: calling future.get()...");
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread: Future.get() interrupted: Error.");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread: Future.get() threw an ExecutionException: Error.");
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread: Future.get() threw an CancellationException: OK.");
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `get()` on a canceled `Future`, you will get a `CancellationException`, hence will not wait for the `Callable`’s code to perform its cleanup. Then, you are just returning and the observed behavior of threads being killed seems to be part of JUnit’s cleanup when it has determined that the test has completed.

In order to wait for the full cleanup, change the last line from

```
executorService.shutdown();
```

to

```
executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Note that it is simpler to declare unexpected exceptions in the method’s `throws` clause rather than cluttering your test code with `catch` clauses calling `Assertions.fail`. JUnit will report such exceptions as failure anyway.

Then, you can remove the entire `sleep` code.

It might be worth putting the `ExecutorService` management into `@Before`/`@After` or even `@BeforeClass`/`@AfterClass` methods, to keep the testing methods free of that, to focus on the actual tests.¹

---

¹ These were the JUnit 4 names. IIRC, the JUnit 5 names are like `@BeforeEach`/`@AfterEach` resp. `@BeforeAll`/`@AfterAll`

Comment: Thank you for your response which is really pertinent. Can you explain why I immediately get a *CancellationException* whereas the callable thread is not yet terminated? That does not seem to match the *Future.get()* manual: ***Waits if necessary** for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.*

Comment: Well, when the future is canceled, its result is the *canceled* state, so there’s no further waiting necessary, to provide *that* result. Or, in other words, nothing that your callable might do after that, will ever change this result. The focus of the future really is the result, not the code that might run in the background. (Even more when it comes to the newer `CompletableFuture`, which doesn’t even know the code that might/will eventually provide the result).